# How to fix: "found : (AnyVal, AnyVal) required: (Double, Double)" with Futures

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future

Compiling error:

> [error]  found   : ((Double, Double)) => scala.concurrent.Future[(Double, Double)]
>
> [error] required: ((AnyVal, AnyVal)) => scala.concurrent.Future[?] [error](c: (Double, Double)) => Future(c).map(x=>x)

IDE is accepting the code just fine.

The code was written using for loop and yield. I tried to simplify it.

```
def f(r: UUID, l: Int) = {
  g(r).flatMap { (c: (Double, Double)) => /*** this part is just for the debugging ***/
    Future(c).map(x=>x)
  }
}

def g(r: UUID) = {
  session.selectOne(
    s"""
      SELECT
        ${RR.x},
        ${RR.y}
      FROM
        ${RR.g}
      WHERE
        ${RR.r} = ?
      ORDER BY
        ${RR.t} DESC
    """,
    r.toString
  ).map {
    case Some(row) => (1.0,1.0) //will be replaced when it is working
    case None => (0,0)
  }
}
```

The compiler find **c** to be of type **(AnyVal, AnyVal)** I want it to be **(Double,Double)**

Comment: Two solutions, first one change the **None** _case_ to `(0.0d, 0.0d)`. secod _(bets one)_, use explicit type signatures on your methods. `def g(r: UUID): (Double, Double)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually complaining that the function signature of the method you're passing into flatmap isn't what it needs.  Try changing your `case None => (0,0)` line to `case None => (0d, 0d)` in your `g` function.  If two case branches are returning different types, it will default to the super type of both. In this case it looks like your `g` function is returning type `(AnyVal,AnyVal)`

Comment: @Lulu if this solved your problem, please take a second to [accept the answer and thereby mark the question as solved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Jeremy, just a little note, it actually will use the _"weak least upper bound"_ of the two branches - in this case `(AnyVal, AnyVal)` _(instead of `Any`)_. Second, since an `Int` can be automatically upcasted to a `Double`, IMHO, the best would be to use explicit type signatures, given that not only serves as documentation and will solve this problem, but also will solve many other _(probably harder)_ problems with type inference in the future.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Regarding "weak least upper bound": Thank you, I stand corrected.  I don't actually know what a weak least upper bound is though.

Comment: @Jeremy neither do I _(at least not in the very formal sense of the expression LOL)_ - but in _"mundane"_ terms, it basically means that it searches for the upper bound that its more specific _(in this case `AnyVal`)_, that ensures you get a good abstraction to work with, because it could use `Any` for everything always. - That for the `least` part, for `weak`, [this](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#weak-conformance) is a very clear definition _(clearer that anything I could write here)_.